# How should controller actions be tested by redirecting in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: unit-testing, redirect, controller, phpunit, zend-framework2

How can controller actions like these:

```
public function redirectFromAction() {
    // route "my-route" is mapped to the action redirectToAction
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('my-route');
}
public function redirectToAction() {
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

be tested with PHPUnit? What can and should be tested? Which asserts? What is special about the testing of controller actions with [request redirecting](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#redirect-plugin)?

It would be nice, if someone could provide an example for the testing of the actions above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doc could help you: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html

I'd test something like this:

```
public function testRedirectAction()
{
    $this->dispatch('/redirect-form');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(301);
    $this->assertResponseHeaderContains('Location' , '/my-route');
}
```

Be sure that you extend you test class from `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase`